# How to keep images in an HTML template inside Outlook from expanding unnecessarily with React?

Tags: css, reactjs, html-email

I'm creating a email generator using React. I'm rendering tables (since that's what an email must have).

In most email browsers the email looks decent, except in Outlook which expands the images and ruins the layout.

Here is the specific component that renders the images:

```
const Ad = ({ image, link, hasDivider, styles = localStyles }) => (
  <>
    <Grid.Row className={styles.container}>
      <a href={link}>
        <span
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            <!--[if mso]>
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img width="100%" src=${image}
                  alt="ad" style="text-align: right; width: 100%; border: 0;
                  text-decoration:none;
                  vertical-align: baseline;">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="display:none">
            <![endif]-->`
          }}
        />
        <Img className={styles.image} src={image} alt="ad" />
        <span
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            <!--[if mso]>
            </div>
            <![endif]-->
            `
          }}
        />
      </a>
    </Grid.Row>
    {hasDivider && (
      <Grid.Row>
        <Divider />
      </Grid.Row>
    )}
  </>
)
```

`Img` component:

```
const Img = ({ src, alt, className, styles = localStyles, style = {} }) => {
  return (
    <img
      src={src}
      alt={alt}
      style={style}
      className={cx(styles.img, className)}
    />
  )
}
```

I'm using "email conditionals" for this which kind of works in more modern Outlook versions.

Comment: We need to see how is your Img component. Try to insert on the img css `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: @Maxwells.c Hi. I just added it, though the conditional do works in Outlook, so it renders the  simple `img` HTML tag.

Answer (score 2):

In the Outlook on Windows (from 2007 to 2019, using Word's rendering engine), percentage widths on `<img>` elements are based on the image file’s physical width, not the parent element’s width as one should expect in CSS. So if your image is 100px wide, `width="100%"` will equal to 100px. And if your image is 2000px wide, it will equal 2000px. The appropriate solution for Outlook is to use a fixed width in pixels via the HTML `width` attribute, and use a `width:100%;` styles for other clients in an inline style (which Outlook will ignore).

You're going to need to update your `Img` component to include the image’s width and render it with something like this:

```
<img width="${width}" src=${image}
                  alt="ad" style="text-align: right; width: 100%; border: 0;
                  text-decoration:none;
                  vertical-align: baseline;">
```

Comment: Did not worked. It´s impossible to work with Outlook.

Comment: Can you share the complete output HTML code you're sending to Outlook? Also can you precise which version of Outlook exactly?