# Responsive images in outlook email

Tags: html, html-email

How can this be done? I want the image to shrink with the page width but that doesn't seem possible for outlook. Its seems like it requires a fixed width attribute on the image tag.

I still want a responsive image in gmail though so is it best to do a conditional?

```
if MSO
<img width=600/>

if !MSO 
<img style="width: 100%"
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: This answer can be helpful for you. please try this method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989897/image-style-height-and-width-not-taken-in-outlook-mails

Comment: Style tags dont work in outlook so no that method doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an answer I gave on [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093699/how-to-keep-images-in-an-html-template-inside-outlook-from-expanding-unnecessari/65093986#65093986) recently.

In the Outlook on Windows (from 2007 to 2019, using Word's rendering engine), percentage widths on `<img>` elements are based on the image file’s physical width, not the parent element’s width as one should expect in CSS. So if your image is 100px wide, `width="100%"` will equal to 100px. And if your image is 2000px wide, it will equal 2000px. The appropriate solution for Outlook is to use a fixed width in pixels via the HTML `width` attribute, and use a `width:100%;` styles for other clients in an inline style (which Outlook will ignore).